# Ionic 4 / Capacitor PWA app doesn't update the latest content from Firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I have created simple Ionic 4 / Capacitor PWA app and it works fine on the device and PC browser. I have a problem when doing a small change and publish to the firebase.

**Note:** On the device where I have used it using the `home icon`.

I have used this and it shows deployment success

```
ionic build --prod
firebase deploy
```

But when I clicked the generated url on the browser it doesn't show the updated content. i.e. text change.
Same on the device. i.e. no change of the text. I have killed the app and load it again. But no effect. After that, I have ctrl+ F5 on the browser and then it shows correct content on both platforms. So can you tell me the correct workflow here? Because I cannot refresh the app on the device. Is this a problem on Firebase hosting on Ionic 4/ Capacitor PWA app or else?

*firebase.json*

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/build/app/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public, max-age=31536000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "ngsw-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I got around it by reloading it with a timestamp:

`window.location = '/' + Date.now();`

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 (browser tools) → Applicatoin → Cache → right click → Refresh Caches.

[image]